# How to inspect a view's structure in information schema in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

Is there a way to discover the structure of a view in a similar way to how tables are described by entries in `information_schema.columns`? I can also use the `pg_*` tables.

In other words, similar to how `psql` has `\d` which describes the structures of both tables and views, I'd like to access this information via SQL queries.

Comment: My goal is not to see the SELECT query which makes the view (that's already available in pg_views, but the columns and their attributes.

Comment: Just as a side note, when you specify `-E` to psql, it will print the query it uses for internal commands like `\d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) already includes views; you can join with [`information_schema.views`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-views.html) if you need to filter to only columns that are part of a view.